# error: Cannot find a matching 0-argument function with XSLT 2.0 with Saxon EE( with License File in Place in same folder that of JAR)

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon, xslt-3.0

I am Using saxon EE processor for conversion of XML with XSLT-2.0. but its giving error for XSL file .

Below is the Code for XSL File

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:setfile ="java:com.output.extensionFile">

<xsl:param name="outDir" select="setfile:getCurrentDir(setfile:new())"/>
 
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Below is the the code where we are calling the transformer for conversion from XML to HTML.

```
{
        javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory tFactory = new EnterpriseTransformerFactory();
        XslImportResolver myResolve = new XslImportResolver();
        tFactory.setURIResolver( myResolve );
        javax.xml.transform.Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer
                        (new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource(xslLocation));
        Registry registry = Registry.getRegistry( this );
        transformer.transform( new StreamSource( xmlLocation ),
                new StreamResult( new FileOutputStream( htmlLocation ) ) );
 }
```

Java code for imported Java class

```
public class extensionFile {
  
  // Empty Constructor
public extensionFile()
{
}

   public Object getCurrentDir()
    {
        return ReportStatic.getCurrentDir();
    }

}
```

We are getting below error :

> Static error at char 22 near {...e:getCurrentDir(setfile:new...} in expression in xsl:param/@select on line 78 column 73 :
> XPST0017: Cannot find a matching 0-argument function named Q{java:com.output.extensionFile}new(). For diagnostics on
> calls to Java methods, use the -TJ command line option or set the Configuration property
> FeatureKeys.TRACE_EXTERNAL_FUNCTIONS

Comment: You need to show the relevant Java code you are trying to call as well.

Comment: @MartinHonnen
 Please find below code
`public class extensionFile {

   public Object getCurrentDir()
    {
        return ReportStatic.getCurrentDir();
    }

}`

Comment: You are getting the error on `Q{java:com.output.extensionFile}new()`: is there no public, parameterless constructor for `extensionFile`?

Comment: And so far the code samples lack the package/namespace declarations to tell from the source code alone if Saxon has any chance to find `com.output.extensionFile`.

Comment: We have empty constructor , placed . we have `com.output.extensionFile` file placed at correct location. 
We are using in other location as well , so its correct .The Extesnion File code i am sharing is dummy one .

Comment: I would suggest to start with running Saxon EE from the command line with the cited `-TJ` option to see where/why Saxon fails to find your Java class/constructor. I am afraid someone here on StackOverflow can only debug your code if you show minimal but complete samples allowing us to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run the suggested diagnostics?

From the information given, the most likely explanations are (a) that the full name of the class is not what you are suggesting, or (b) that the class is not on the classpath. The -TJ diagnostics should reveal the explanation.

Comment: Hi can suggest how can i give a absolute path , any example would work for me

Comment: Please try running the diagnostics with -TJ and tell us the result.